# I can't remember or find my password for the internet connection HOME-6EC2. I am currently connected

Tags: windows-7, windows

How can I find my password for my current internet connection HOME-6EC2?

Comment: Is this a wireless connection?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Network Connections window by right-clicking on your network icon in the System Tray and selecting "Open Network and Sharing Center". Click the "Change adapter settings" link in the left menu.

Right-click on your wireless adapter. This may be labeled "Wi-Fi", or it may have the manufacturer's name. Select "Status" from the menu.

Open the connection's Properties window. Click wireless properties, and click the security tab.
Check the "Show Characters" box and your wireless password will be displayed.